# Java ArrayList Output Error

Tags: java, arraylist, output

In this program, I am getting incorrect output for the ArrayList.
In the first line, it always prints every single element of the ArrayList horizontally.
It then will correctly print the ArrayList.
Can someone take a look at the code and see if I did something wrong? I will show you the two classes.

Class 1:

```
 public class contactDriver
 {
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {                       
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.println ("What would you like to do?");  
           int answer;
           System.out.println ("Press 1 to add a contact.");          
           System.out.println ("Press 2 to display all contacts.");

           answer = scan.nextInt();

           ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        contacts.add(new Contact("Patrick McGee", "334-555-8860", "pmcgee123@gmail.com"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("John Appleseed", "142-555-6740", "jappleseed99@gmail.com"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Matt Jordan", "213-555-2323", "mjordan23@gmail.com"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Kanye East", "255-434-9909", "keast123@gmail.com"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Derrick Flower", "144-555-1111", "dflower1@gmail.com"));

           if (answer == 1){
              System.out.println ("Please enter the first and last name of the contact.");
              String name = scan.next();
              scan.nextLine();

              System.out.println ("Please enter the phone number of the contact.");
              String num = scan.next();
              scan.nextLine();

              System.out.println ("Please enter the email of the contact.");
              String email = scan.next();
              scan.nextLine();

              contacts.add(new Contact(name, num, email));

              }

           if (answer == 2){
              }
              System.out.println(contacts);
              for(Contact c : contacts) {
              System.out.println(c);
```

Class 2:

```
 public class Contact
{
public Contact(String name, String num, String email)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.num = num;
  this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstname()
{
  return name;
}

public String getNum()
{
  return num;
}

public String getEmail()
{
  return email;
}


public String toString()
{
  return "Contact[" + name + ", " + num + ", " + email + "]";
}

private String name;
private String num;
private String email;

}
```

**The output:**

[Contact[Patrick McGee, 334-555-8860, pmcgee123@gmail.com], Contact[John Appleseed, 142-555-6740, jappleseed99@gmail.com], Contact[Matt Jordan, 213-555-2323, mjordan23@gmail.com], Contact[Kanye East, 255-434-9909, keast123@gmail.com], Contact[Derrick Flower, 144-555-1111, dflower1@gmail.com]
(all in one line).

**Then prints:**
                                                                                     Contact[Patrick McGee, 334-555-8860, pmcgee123@gmail.com]
Contact[John Appleseed, 142-555-6740, jappleseed99@gmail.com]
... so on.

Any ideas on the fix?

Thanks :)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output

> [Contact[Patrick McGee, 334-555-8860, pmcgee123@gmail.com], Contact[John Appleseed, 142-555-6740, jappleseed99@gmail.com], Contact[Matt Jordan, 213-555-2323, mjordan23@gmail.com], Contact[Kanye East, 255-434-9909, keast123@gmail.com], Contact[Derrick Flower, 144-555-1111, dflower1@gmail.com]

is due to

```
System.out.println(contacts);
```

This prints a `String` representation (by the method [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29)) of the `ArrayList contacts`.

**Edit**

To don't get this output just delete that line. The `for` you are using to print each `Contact` looks fine:

```
for(Contact c : contacts) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I change it to to solve this issue?

Comment: Oh I totally missed that! xD Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You've an extra sysout statement which is printing the extra values. `System.out.println(contacts);` prints all the elements of the array list(All contacts in one line).

> [Contact[Patrick McGee, 334-555-8860, pmcgee123@gmail.com], Contact[John Appleseed, 142-555-6740, jappleseed99@gmail.com], Contact[Matt Jordan, 213-555-2323, mjordan23@gmail.com], Contact[Kanye East, 255-434-9909, keast123@gmail.com], Contact[Derrick Flower, 144-555-1111, dflower1@gmail.com]

I guess you just wanted to print the plain text "contacts" and then print each and every contact, like this.

```
if (answer == 2){
    System.out.println("contacts:"); // prints the plain text contacts
    for(Contact c : contacts) {
        System.out.println(c); // prints each contact using the toString() implementation provided by you
    }
}
```

And if you do not want to print any text before printing each contact in the list, then just remove the extra sysout statement.

```
if (answer == 2){
    // System.out.println(contacts); // not needed - commented/deleted
    for(Contact c : contacts) {
        System.out.println(c); // prints each contact using the toString() implementation provided by you
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the problem is. I'm not sure if the issue is it printing horizontally in one line (although it seems you have figured out how to get it to print on multiple lines), or if that the problem is that it is printing twice, once on one line and once on multiple.

I'm going to try and explain why it does what it does, maybe that will help you. If you can clarify what the issue is I'm sure I could help if this doesn't answer your question.

So, I'm not sure if this was intentional or not, but the if statement at the bottom of your first class has nothing inside its code block. It has no purpose unless you put code inside of it, if you don't plan on doing that, you could go ahead and remove it.

```
if (answer == 2){
          }
          System.out.println(contacts);
          for(Contact c : contacts) {
          System.out.println(c);
```

As you can see, the curly brace underneath it is stopping any of that code from being inside executed by the if statement. All of that code will be ran with the program regardless of whether or not the 1 or 2 was inputted. If you wish for some of that code underneath (or all) to be ran when number 2 is inputted, put it inside those curly braces. Otherwise you can leave it out and it will run regardless of the option selected.

There are two things happening at the end of the first class.

```
System.out.println(contacts);
```

This is telling it to print the entire arraylist in one line. That is why you get the horizontal line of all contacts.

```
    for(Contact c: contacts){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

This is telling it to loop through the arraylist and print each individual contact on its own separate line. That is why you get the 2nd output. Please note that in your original post you were missing a curly brace after the bottom for loop, I added it in this post.

I hope that clears up any confusion. You should be able to choose if you want both of those outputs, or if you want one or both to run only when option 2 is selected. Again, I wasn't really sure what the issue was, so I tried to just give an overview of what the code was doing. I apologize that this post was so lengthy. Clearly the other people answering did a better job of using less text. Good luck on your code!